# Two nodes in cluster showing DN to each other, UN to everyone else

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a nine node Cassandra cluster and everything seems to be working fine, except for two of my servers show each other as DN.  All other nodes in the cluster show all nodes as UN.  These two show all nodes UN except for each other, where they show each other as DN.  There are no errors in the system.log on either server that indicates a problem.  All nodes are listed as seed nodes across the cluster.  I am able to telnet between the servers on port 7001, so I don't think it is a network issue.  We are using Internode Communication Encryption so I wonder if it might be an issue with that?

Related Nodetool Status Snippet on 64.6.220.249:

```
DN  64.6.220.251    106.19 GB  256     ?       e008bc26-5d12-48b5-a381-6a175b085496  Rack1
```

Related Nodetool Status Snippet on 64.6.220.251:

```
DN  64.6.220.249    105.31 GB  256     ?       59709c2a-6270-40be-a444-042bdf18873e  Rack1
```

Related Nodetol Status Snippet from another node in the cluster (all nodes show this, except for the two above):

```
UN  64.6.220.251    106.19 GB  256     ?       e008bc26-5d12-48b5-a381-6a175b085496  Rack1
UN  64.6.220.249    105.31 GB  256     ?       59709c2a-6270-40be-a444-042bdf18873e  Rack1
```

GossipInfo ran from 64.6.220.249:

```
/64.6.220.251
generation:1473238188
  heartbeat:12693992
  SCHEMA:a7b7f6f4-24ba-3153-90cc-dc8ad2754251
  RACK:Rack1
  SEVERITY:0.0
  RPC_ADDRESS:64.6.220.251
  HOST_ID:e008bc26-5d12-48b5-a381-6a175b085496
  INTERNAL_IP:64.6.220.251
  X_11_PADDING:{"workload":"Cassandra","active":"true"}
  LOAD:1.14019618013E11
  NET_VERSION:8
  DC:Cassandra-ALPHA
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.1.5.469
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1122920019547920198
```

GossipInfo ran from 64.6.220.251:

```
  /64.6.220.249
  generation:1473237564
  heartbeat:12696040
  RACK:Rack1
  DC:Cassandra-ALPHA
  RPC_ADDRESS:64.6.220.249
  SCHEMA:a7b7f6f4-24ba-3153-90cc-dc8ad2754251
  INTERNAL_IP:64.6.220.249
  SEVERITY:0.0
  X_11_PADDING:{"workload":"Cassandra","active":"true"}
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.1.5.469
  NET_VERSION:8
  LOAD:1.13072884091E11
  HOST_ID:59709c2a-6270-40be-a444-042bdf18873e
  STATUS:NORMAL,-1027844444513030305
```

Nodetool describecluster from 64.6.220.249:

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: Fusion Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        a7b7f6f4-24ba-3153-90cc-dc8ad2754251: [64.6.220.254, 170.75.212.226, 170.75.212.225, 64.6.220.252, 170.75.212.224, 64.6.220.253, 64.6.220.250, 64.6.220.249]

        UNREACHABLE: [64.6.220.251]
```

Nodetool describecluster from 64.6.220.251:

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: Fusion Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        a7b7f6f4-24ba-3153-90cc-dc8ad2754251: [64.6.220.254, 170.75.212.226, 170.75.212.225, 64.6.220.252, 170.75.212.224, 64.6.220.253, 64.6.220.250, 64.6.220.251]

        UNREACHABLE: [64.6.220.249]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why these two nodes show each other as "DN", even though all other nodes see them as "UN?

Comment: A little late..but did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem with 2 of my 16-node cluster. I have tried: 1)stopping and restarting them 2) disable enable gossip but nothing changed!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this "mixed" gossip state before.  When this happens, typically bouncing the cassandra process on the nodes being reported as "DN" fixes it.

Also, when you see this it's also a good idea to run a `nodetool describecluster`.  You should check the results to ensure that you only have one schema version.  If you have multiple schema versions (known as "schema disagreement") it's best to bounce those affected nodes as well.

I'm not entirely sure as to *why* this happens, but a contributing factor is having too many nodes designated as "seed nodes."  When you have too many seed nodes, their gossip states can take longer to get in-sync, and that may lead to this condition.

Comment: Couldn't edit to change this (6 character limit), but the command was actually `nodetool describecluster`. Just wanted to mention that for documentation purposes.  I tried stopping both problem nodes, then starting back up but I'm still having the issue.  Same with a rolling restart of them.  I've edited my question with the output from describecluster.

Comment: @gsteiner Ack...auto-correct!  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue too with Cassandra version 2.2.13 following a few nodes being restarted soon after each other (10-15 minutes apart).

What's interesting is that looking at all the nodes in the cluster, using `nodetool status`, it's clear that the bulk of the nodes had a consensus on which nodes are UP or DN, and only a few nodes didn't have consensus.

My solution was to `nodetool status` on all nodes, identify the ones with inconsistent views, restart those nodes and tail the cassandra logs on the consistent nodes until you see the restarted (rogue) node is online with an entry like `INFO  02:15:31 InetAddress /18.136.19.11 is now UP`, and then move onto the next rogue node until all nodes are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 nodes on status DN but they were actually UP and functioning.
I refreshed the gossip on both nodes and it solved the problem by running:
nodetool disablegossip && nodetool enablegossip

hope this helps.